# how to set position of JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm creating this `JOptionPane`

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File was saved", "Save", 
   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

but my JFrame is big so it is scrollable. When I call this command, a window is created in the bottom right corner and I can only see the header. How I can change the position of this `JOptionPane`?

Comment: you can change `this` for whatever `JComponent`, for example declared as local variable, then you can pass `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myButton, "File...`, JOptionPane must be called on the EDT

Comment: yea thx I change this to null and now it is in the midlle thx but you answer in comment and I cant finish this question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the api 1.6:

> the first parameter is **parentComponent**:
>
> Defines the Component that is to be the parent of this dialog box. It is used in two ways: the Frame that contains it is used as the Frame parent for the dialog box, and its screen coordinates are used in the placement of the dialog box. In general, the dialog box is placed just below the component. This parameter may be null, in which case a default Frame is used as the parent, and the dialog will be centered on the screen (depending on the L&F).

So there isn't no parameter to set the position of the JOptionPane, but you could at least pass `null` as *first parameter* to be sure your JOptionPane is well visible and centered.

Comment: yea null helps me now it it in the middle

Answer (score 3):

You could create a JDialog out of a JOptionPane (see the JOptionPane API to see how to do this), and then display it anywhere you'd like as you can with any JDialog. By the way, perhaps you want to make your JFrame smaller by using JTabbedPanes or CardLayout so you don't have this problem.